# Non-self-referential undecidable sentences in arithmetic

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness

Are there any known undecidable sentences for PA are neither "self-referential" (like a sentence equivalent to its own nonprovability) nor imply consistency of PA (like in the Paris Harrington theorem)?

Comment: The Paris-Harrington statement is not equivalent to the consistency of $\mathsf{PA}$. And yes, there are plenty of examples, many of them discussed in this site.

Comment: I am not sure how one should define _self-referential_. For example, are consistency statements necessarily self-referential? Anyway, there are lots of theories whose strengths are strictly between PA and PA+Con(PA). See "Slow consistency" by Sy Friedman, Michael Rathjen, and Andreas Weiermann  in Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 164 (2013) 382–393, for example. I would be grateful if someone can mention some older references, because I cannot find a good one myself.

Answer (score 2):

Goodstein's Theorem is the most obvious example of an undecidable sentence in PA, and it doesn't imply consistency of PA on its own, but it implies Gentzen's consistency theorem and is required to prove that Goodstein's theorem is undecidable in PA. But all proofs of undecidability must either prove consistency or assume it as an axiom of the independence/undecidability proof.

Basically any proof of undecidability requires either self-reference paradox tricks or a consistency proof. If you can't prove consistency then there's the possibility of some hidden statement out there that makes the system inconsistent and everything decidable, because from a contradiction you can prove anything. Self reference tricks work to prove undecidability of themselves because they imply either undecidability or inconsistency.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem

Comment: "Goodstein's Theorem is the most obvious example of an undecidable sentence in PA, and it doesn't imply consistency of PA". Mmh, I think that Goodstein's theorem does well prove the consistency of PA.

Comment: You're right, Kirby showed that Goodstein's theorem leads to Gentzen's theorem. I don't know that there are nonstandard models of ZFC that are constructable that have Goodstein's theorem and Gentzen's theorem independent. I'll edit my answer to reflect it, thanks.