# Can all undecidable statements on natural numbers be given by Godel's numbering

Tags: logic, natural-numbers

In the standard proof for Godel incompleteness theorem he code our language with Godel's numbering and of course there are is a lot of freedom in our coding. The proof then provide us with an undecidable statement about the natural numbers.
I wonder if it's known whether or not all undecidable statements (maybe up to some isomorphism) can be achieved in this way using a suitable coding for each such statement.

Comment: Are you asking "does every undecidable statement have a Goedel number"? Or are you asking "is there a (nice) way to assign numbers to the set of undecidable statements"? If so, can you be more specific about what sort of numbering you're interested in? It follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61144/473276) that the set of statements that PA does not decide is not even recursively enumerable, so does that answer your question..?

Comment: As in the comment above, I am not entirely sure what you are asking. But, when considering whether **all** undecidable statements can be captured by "a suitable coding," a good first question is whether the outcome of your question is a system with enumerable undecidable statements. If so, this will not work: You could apply the same sort of undecidability approach to "PA + (enumeration of undecidable statements)" to exhibit the existence of an unprovable (unlisted) truth.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes, I am asking "does every undecidable statement have a Godel number"

Comment: The answer to that is "yes, because every statement has a Goedel number". Is that really what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I don't understand. When I say that every statement has a Godel number I mean a Godel number which the standard proof shows it is undecidable. My question is probably on the edge of metamathematics, but I believe it is a precise question

Comment: Aha, OK, I think I'm more or less with you now! Would you be happy with an answer to "is there a statement independent of PA, which PA does not prove is equivalent to any Goedel sentence"? I think that [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2012.11.009) paper from Lawrence Wong's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/638746/473276) shows the answer to that is "yes, there is such a statement" (because any sentence that says "I am not provable in PA" implies Con(PA)). The answer there also gives some nice examples of PA-undecidable statements that don't "look" like a Goedel sentence.

Comment: "I mean a Goedel number which the standard proof shows it is undecidable": that is a bit of a misstatement, the theorem is about undecidability of a statement, not undecidability of the corresponding Goedel number, which is meaningless.  --  Indeed, I too find the question unclear: my guess is you are asking *if there is a way to prove there exist undecidable statements without going through Goedel numbering and machinery such as in GIT overall*.  Is that it?

Comment: P.S.  Moreover, I/we should say *unprovable*, not *undecidable*: these are *not* synonyms...